# Source path of loop-device

Tags: linux, loop-device

Out of curiosity, I would like to know is there a way to find out the source of mounted partition?

For example, output of `df -h` is:

> /dev/loop1  3M 3M 0 100% /media/loop

From this output, I know a loop device of 3M is mounted at `/media/loop`, but I have no clue to determine the exact location of the `/dev/loop1` device.

```
root@SHW:~# mount -o loop /home/SHW/Downloads/TinyCore-current.iso
/mnt/loop mount: block device /home/SHW/Downloads/TinyCore-current.iso is write-protected, mounting read-only
root@SHW:~# tail -n1 /proc/mounts
/dev/loop1 /mnt/loop iso9660 ro,relatime 0 0
```

How do I find out the absolute path of `/dev/loop1` f I don't know who mounted those partitions? (In this case the path is `/home/SHW/Downloads/TinyCore-current.iso`.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`losetup`'s `--list` option](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/losetup.8.html):

```
$ losetup --list /dev/loop0
NAME       SIZELIMIT OFFSET AUTOCLEAR RO BACK-FILE
/dev/loop0         0      0         0  0 /tmp/backing-file
```

If you **only** want the file, use the `-O` option to pick the column:

```
$ losetup --list --noheadings -O BACK-FILE /dev/loop0
/tmp/backing-file
```

This option is part of recent versions of `util-linux`. Earlier versions support only the [`-a`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/losetup) option, which lists all active devices in a harder-to-process format:

```
$ losetup -a
/dev/loop0: []: (/tmp/backing-file)
```

Either way, it's not overly onerous to process however you want.

Comment: One can also just use `losetup /dev/(target)`.

Answer (score 3):

To get the backing file path use:

```
cat /sys/block/loop1/loop/backing_file
```

Comment: This is a great option since `losetup` may not always be available

Answer (score -2):

> I have no clue to determine the exact location of /dev/loop1 device.

What do you mean by the exact location of `/dev/loop1` device? `/dev/loop*` where * is a number are loopback (virtual) devices, which are used to mount filesystems that are not located on other block devices, such as hard disks. You can enumerate them and see where they are mounted, using the `mount` command and you can setup a new one using the `losetup` command.

If you want to know to which physical device a `/dev/` node is attached, then there are ways to do that. You can use `udevadm` to query udev. On my system, the following commands give more information about the `sda` disk:

```
$ udevadm info --query=path --name=sda
/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.2/ata4/host3/target3:0:0/3:0:0:0/block/sda
$ udevadm info --query=symlink --name=sda
disk/by-id/ata-ST3500418AS_6VMD78AY disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000c500224ac74f
```

In addition to these, you can use `lspci` to get more information about where the device is physically attached. On my system, `/dev/sda` is attached to the sata controller:

```
$ lspci
[snip]
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
[snip]
```