# Who owned the directory and how to remove it?

Tags: directory, ownership

```
ls  -l  /media/debian9/disk
total 1741
drwxr-xr-x  2 100000 100000       3 Jul 20  2018 acct
-rwxr-xr-x  1 100000 100000    1102 Jul 20  2018 anbox-init.sh
```

Who is the 100000?

```
cat /etc/passwd  |grep  100000
```

Nothing as output.

And i want to remove it.

```
sudo rm -rf  /media/debian9/disk
rm: cannot remove '/media/debian9/disk/xx': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/media/debian9/disk/yy': Read-only file system
```

I remount the filesystem as read-write with:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /media/debian9/disk
mount: cannot remount /dev/loop5 read-write, is write-protected
```

Comment: Which type of filesystem is mounted on that directory? Where does it come from?

Comment: Related: [Source path of loop-device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144425/source-path-of-loop-device)

Comment: Are you looking at a mounted installation ISO image?

Comment: why do you want to delete the directory? .... it seems that you do not know what it is for ..... what will you do if deleting the directory breaks your system?

Comment: It looks like he is running Anbox, an android emulator. See [How do I hide the loop partitions in Nautilus created by Snap app?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/912538/how-do-i-hide-the-loop-partitions-in-nautilus-created-by-snap-app) / [anbox-init.sh github](https://github.com/anbox/anbox/blob/master/scripts/anbox-init.sh)

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/loop5` is a read-only virtual device. But you can try to unmount it (`umount /dev/loop5`).

Comment: Read the question again

Comment: The questions asks "...and how to remove it?" My answer: You remove it by unmounting it. What's wrong with that?